# Bash script placing quotes around command

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that will get an IP to use as part of an SSH tunnel, but running this script the SSH tunnel fails. When using `set -x` I can see it places the arguments to the SSH command in single quotes and manually running this line results in the same error.

The Script:

```
ssh -N -L 9000:${ip_array[$2]}:443 ssh-server
```

The first argument is used elsewhere in the script for something else which is why the second is used here. `ssh-server` is an alias in my SSH config to the server i am tunneling through.

The output I get is:

```
ssh -N -L '9000:"172.0.0.1":443' ssh-server
```

Could this be because the script to fetch the IP returns strings to the array?

Comment: what is inside ip_array[$2], can you echo "${ip_array[$2]}" (mind the quotes!)

Comment: It does return the IP as `"172.0.0.1"` with the quotes, could this be the issue?

Comment: obviously, the array contains the string `'"172.0.0.1"'` and not the string `'172.0.0.1'`. You should check the source for the array, or how it is created. You could also simply remove the quotes: `echo "${ip_array[$2]//"/}"`

Comment: @Luke this is the issue. If the variable has quotes (which is normally what you'd want) then you might need to remove them possibly with $(echo ${ip_array[$2]} | sed -E 's/(^")|("$)//g')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try removing the double-quotes first :

```
ip=$(echo "${ip_array[$2]}" | sed "s/\"//g")
ssh -N -L 9000:${ip}:443 ssh-server
```

Comment: `ip=$(sed 's/"//g' <<< "${ip_array[$2]}"` to be even more concise.

Comment: @codeforester how does that differ from my answer ? Is it just to avoid the pipe ?

Answer (score 1):

Or just use shell parameter expansion to remove the quotes:

```
ssh -N -L 9000:${ip_array[$2]//"/}:443 ssh-server
```

That lone double quote may mess up your editor's syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes by piping it through the `tr` command:

```
ssh -N -L 9000:$( echo ${ip_array[$2]} | tr -d '"' ):443 ssh-server
```